# Trying to get property of non-object - CodeIgniter Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, klout

I am new to codeigniter and i am  trying to integrate Klout API to codeigniter and i have this error saying Trying to get property of non-object Here

I have places the API out side of the application folder

My will be KloutAPIv2.class

```
<?php
// Define

DEFINE("HTTP_GET","GET");
DEFINE("HTTP_POST","POST");

// Get Started

class KloutAPIv2 {

/** @var String $BaseUrl The base url for the Klout API */
private $BaseUrl = "http://api.klout.com/";

/** @var String $Version YYYYMMDD */
private $Version = '20120511'; 

/** @var String $KloutKey */
private $KloutKey;

/**
 * Constructor for the API
 * Prepares the request URL and client api params
 * @param String $client_id
 * @param String $client_secret
 * @param String $version Defaults to v2, appends into the API url
 */
public function  __construct($kloutapi_key = false, $version="v2"){
    $this->BaseUrl = "{$this->BaseUrl}$version/";
    $this->KloutKey = $kloutapi_key;
}

/******************************************************/
//       Identity
/******************************************************/

/** 
 * KloutIDLookupByName
 * Looks up a Klout ID from a Screen Name
 * @param String $network The network to look the screen name up on
 * @param String $screenName The screen name to look up
 */
public function KloutIDLookupByName($network, $screenname){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl . "identity.json/". $network;
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['screenName'] = $screenname;
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    $CurlResult = $this->GET($url,$params);
    $ResultString = json_decode($CurlResult);
    // Assume it only returns "ks" data:
    $KloutID = $ResultString->id;

    return $KloutID; 
}

/** 
 * KloutIDLookupByID
 * Looks up a Klout ID from a Twitter ID
 * @param String $network The network to look the screen name up on
 * @param String $id The screen name to look up
 */
public function KloutIDLookupByID($network, $id){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl . "identity.json/". $network ."/". $id;
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    $CurlResult = $this->GET($url,$params);
    $ResultString = json_decode($CurlResult);
    // Assume it only returns "ks" data:
    $KloutID = $ResultString->id;

    return $KloutID; 
}


/** 
 * KloutIDLookupReverse
 * Looks up a Klout ID from a Twitter ID
 * @param String $network The network to look the screen name up on
 * @param String $id The screen name to look up
 */
public function KloutIDLookupReverse($network, $id){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl . "identity.json/klout/". $id ."/". $network;
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    return $this->GET($url,$params);

}
/******************************************************/
//       User
/******************************************************/

/** 
 * KloutUser
 * Looks up Klout User Data
 * @param String $id The Klout ID to look up
 */
public function KloutUser($id){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl ."user.json/". $id;
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    return $this->GET($url,$params);

}

/** 
 * KloutUserScore
 * Looks up Klout User Score
 * @param String $id The Klout ID to look up
 */
public function KloutUserScore($id){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl ."user.json/". $id ."/score";
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    return $this->GET($url,$params);

}

/** 
 * KloutUserTopics
 * Looks up Klout User Topics
 * @param String $id The Klout ID to look up
 */
public function KloutUserTopics($id){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl ."user.json/". $id ."/topics";
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    return $this->GET($url,$params);

}

/** 
 * KloutUserInfluence
 * Looks up Klout User Influence
 * @param String $id The Klout ID to look up
 */
public function KloutUserInfluence($id){
    // Build the URL
    $url = $this->BaseUrl ."user.json/". $id ."/influence";
    // Append the lookup details
    $params['key'] = $this->KloutKey;
    // Return the result;
    return $this->GET($url,$params);

}



/******************************************************/
//       Scores
/******************************************************/

/** 
 * KloutScore
 * Looks up Klout Score, does not return any other data
 * @param String $id The Klout ID to look up
 */
public function KloutScore($id){
    // Use the Klout Score Data call to pull just the Score
    $CurlResult = $this->KloutUserScore($id);
    $ResultString = json_decode($CurlResult);
    $KloutScore = $ResultString->score;

    return $KloutScore; 
}

/** 
 * KloutScore
 * Returns changes in klout score
 * @param String $id The Klout ID to look up
 * @param String $period options are either day, week, month
 */
public function KloutScoreChanges($id, $period){
    // Use the Klout Score Data call to pull just the Score
    $CurlResult = $this->KloutUserScore($id);
    $ResultString = json_decode($CurlResult);
    if ($period == "day") {
        $KloutScoreChanges = $ResultString->scoreDelta->dayChange;
    } elseif ($period == "week") {
        $KloutScoreChanges = $ResultString->scoreDelta->weekChange;
    } else {
        $KloutScoreChanges = $ResultString->scoreDelta->monthChange;
    }
    return $KloutScoreChanges; 
}




/******************************************************/
//       Utility
/******************************************************/

/**
 * Request
 * Performs a cUrl request with a url generated by MakeUrl. 
 * @param String $url The base url to query
 * @param Array $params The parameters to pass to the request
 */
private function Request($url,$params=false,$type=HTTP_GET){

    // Populate data for the GET request
    if($type == HTTP_GET) $url = $this->MakeUrl($url,$params);

    // borrowed from Andy Langton: http://andylangton.co.uk/
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
    }else {
        // Handle the useragent like we are Google Chrome
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.');
    }
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Populate the data for POST
    if($type == HTTP_POST){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        if($params) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    }

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    $info=curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

/**
 * GET
 * Abstraction of the GET request
 */
private function GET($url,$params=false){
    return $this->Request($url,$params,HTTP_GET);
}

/**
 * POST
 * Abstraction of a POST request
 */
private function POST($url,$params=false){
    return $this->Request($url,$params,HTTP_POST);
}

/**
 * MakeUrl
 * Takes a base url and an array of parameters and sanitizes the data, then creates a complete
 * url with each parameter as a GET parameter in the URL (Credit to Stephen Young)
 * @param String $url The base URL to append the query string to (without any query data)
 * @param Array $params The parameters to pass to the URL
 */ 
private function MakeUrl($url,$params){
    if(!empty($params) && $params){
        foreach($params as $k=>$v) $kv[] = "$k=$v";
        $url_params = str_replace(" ","+",implode('&',$kv));
        $url = trim($url) . '?' . $url_params;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

}
?>

and I create a controller as klout.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class klout extends CI_Controller {

    public $kloutapi_key;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->file('./klout/KloutAPIv2.class.php');
        $this->kloutapi_key = 'key';
    }

    public function kloutID() {

        $network = "twitter";
        $userid = 318066771330736;

       $klout = new KloutAPIv2($this->kloutapi_key);
     $kloutid = $klout->KloutIDLookupByID($network, $userid);

        print_r($kloutid);
        exit();

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code. Where exactly is the error?

Comment: $kloutid = has to be the error, it's the only place he's trying to get  a property. Try printing out what $klout is returning, if it isn't returning anything or is returning an array that is your issue.

Comment: when I print $klout i get this result KloutAPIv2 Object ( [BaseUrl:KloutAPIv2:private] => http://api.klout.com/v2/ [Version:KloutAPIv2:private] => 20120511 [KloutKey:KloutAPIv2:private] => 3w6jad5bjkf... )

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight variation to accomodate for Twitter IDs versus Twitter screen names: the URL structure is different, and the 'network' string is different:

- When calling by ID, the network is "tw"
- When calling by Screen Name, the network is "twitter"

[This is mostly a workaround of our API Proxy's route matching system].

So, by ID:
http://api.klout.com/v2/identity.json/tw/318066771330736?key=foo

By Screen Name:
http://api.klout.com/v2/identity.json/twitter?screenName=jack&key=foo

Answer (score 0):

I think you must load your code as a library, not using `$this->load->file`, I check Code Igniter user guide about `$this->load->file`:

> $this->load->file('filepath/filename', true/false)
>
> This is a generic file loading function. Supply the filepath and name
>   in the first parameter and it will open and read the file. By default
>   the data is sent to your browser, just like a View file, but if you
>   set the second parameter to true (boolean) it will instead return the
>   data as a string.

So, my recomendation is to use a library. Put your `KloutAPIv2.class.php` in a file called `klout.php` in your application/libraries folder and load it usign `$this->load->library('kout');`

You can pass parameter to constructor when you're loading your library, as shown in this example:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
$this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
```

More information: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Hey thank you.. but when i do that way also i get an 500 Internal Server Error